# PGFplots marks mandatory for 1st and last point

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to plot values from a big table. Since it has too many numbers, I want to draw the line and only some marks (because there is other lines in the plot, therefore, to avoid confusion). I know that I can use `mark repeat={<integer>}` for that (or use `each nth point={<integer>}`, depending on the situation). However, with that, I know that the first point in the graphic will have a mark, put not always the last point, because it depends on the `<integer>`.

How can I draw always a mark for the first and last points and some in the middle of both, automatically?

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=0pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}

\pgfplotstableread{%
x1 y1
1 2
2 4
3 1
4 5
5 9
6 11
7 15
8 12
9 10
10 1
}\mytable

\pgfplotsset{mytick x interval/.style args={#1:#2:#3}{%
        xmin=#1,xmax=#3,xincrement={#1}{#2},
        xtick={#1,\xval,...,#3}
    },
    xincrement/.code 2 args={\pgfmathparse{#1+#2}\xdef\xval{\pgfmathresult}}
}

\pgfplotsset{mytick y interval/.style args={#1:#2:#3}{%
        ymin=#1,ymax=#3,yincrement={#1}{#2},
        ytick={#1,\yval,...,#3}
    },
    yincrement/.code 2 args={\pgfmathparse{#1+#2}\xdef\yval{\pgfmathresult}}
}

\pgfplotsset{every tick/.style={black,}}

\pgfplotsset{%
    compat=1.8,
    compat/show suggested version=false,
    mytick x interval=0:1:10,
    mytick y interval=0:1:15,
    xlabel={x-axis},
    ylabel={y-axis},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[mark options={fill=white,solid}]
    \addplot[thick,mark=pentagon*,mark repeat={2}] table[x=x1, y=y1] {\mytable};
  \legend{val}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A simple way would be to use `\addplot[thick,mark=pentagon*,mark repeat={2}] table {\mytable} plot coordinates {+(0,0)};`, but this would lead to the final plot mark being drawn twice if it is already included with the "real" plot marks. I guess that's not what you had in mind?

Comment: @Jake you are right. Each mark shall be drawn only one time.

Comment: I was thinking in something like (which I don't know if really works): get the first value; get the last value; do some calculations between both (and setting an interval) and round the result to be used as `<value>` in `mark repeat={<value>}`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use the `scatter` functionality, which allows you to execute code before each marker. In that code, you can then check whether `\coordindex` (the index of the current marker, starting at 0) is the same as `\numcoords-1` (the total number of coordinates).

Here's a style `mark repeat*=<n>`, which draws every `n`th marker and the final marker:

```
\pgfplotsset{
    mark repeat*/.style={
        scatter,
        scatter src=x,
        scatter/@pre marker code/.code={
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro\usemark{
                or(mod(\coordindex,#1)==0, (\coordindex==(\numcoords-1))
            }
            \ifnum\usemark=0
                \pgfplotsset{mark=none}
            \fi
        },
        scatter/@post marker code/.code={}
    }
}
```

[image]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=0pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}

\pgfplotstableread{%
x1 y1
1 2
2 4
3 1
4 5
5 9
6 11
7 15
8 12
9 10
10 1
}\mytable

\pgfplotsset{
    mark repeat*/.style={
        scatter,
        scatter src=x,
        scatter/@pre marker code/.code={
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro\usemark{
                or(mod(\coordindex,#1)==0, (\coordindex==(\numcoords-1))
            }
            \ifnum\usemark=0
                \pgfplotsset{mark=none}
            \fi
        },
        scatter/@post marker code/.code={}
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[mark options={fill=white,solid}]
    \addplot[
            mark=pentagon*, thick,
            mark repeat*=2
    ] table[x=x1, y=y1] {\mytable};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! It indeed works. However, I am not sure if it is "elegant" using the `opacity`, because the mark is drawn in both cases, only the opacity is set to 1 or 0.

Comment: @cacamailg: You're absolutely right. I've edited my answer.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for :).

Comment: @cacamailg: I've improved the answer a little bit further by not relying on the `\pgfplotspointmetatransformed` macro, which is prone to numerical inaccuracies, but instead using `\numcoords`, which contains the total number of coordinates.

Comment: the code above does not work if `each nth point={}` is also used. How can I put both working together?