# How can I plot conditional functions with Pgfplots?

Tags: plot

I want to plot the following function:

[image]

I can easily use Pgfplots to plot each section, but I could not unite the two functions without using a vertical function (which I think is an ugly solution). Is there a way to correctly plot conditional functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Description

You can put any pgfmath expression (see pgf manual, chapter: "Mathematical Expressions") as parameter to `\addplot`: In your case:

```
ifthenelse( <condition>, <then>, <else>)
```

or the short form:

```
<condition> ? <then> : <else>
```

**Note:** You could also mark the discontinuity, instead of drawing a vertical line (see [How can I add open and closed circles on either side of a jump discontinuity?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/200892/123129)).

#### Result

[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xmin=0]
        %\addplot[red, samples=300] { ifthenelse(x > 4, 0, .1*(.5*x-4)^2) };
        \addplot[blue, samples=300] { x > 4 ? 0 : .1*(.5*x-4)^2 };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect answer! Thank you very much! never thought to check the manual will do that next time!